# seek(0) method in RandAccessFile deleting my content

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

In this project, I want to place each new number at the beginning of the random access file. But the seek() method deletes every other number in the file. I don't know why.

```
package first;

import java.io.*;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        File file = new File("test.dat");
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
        raf.setLength(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            raf.writeInt(i);
            raf.seek(0);//setting the pointer to the beginning of the file
        }

        //printing the numbers
        System.out.println(raf.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            raf.seek(i * 4);
            System.out.println(raf.readInt());

        }

    }

}
```

The console output is thus

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.readInt(RandomAccessFile.java:846)
    at liangweb/chapter37.Demo.main(Demo.java:20)
4
9
```

Comment: Why do you expect another outcome? `RandomAccessFile.writeInt()` does no "insert" operation - it just writes the 4 bytes from the current position (overwriting whatever is there, or appending to the file if the current position is at the end of the file)

Comment: @ThomasKläger then how to I perform the task with RandomAccessFile class, since my approach wasn't valid?

Comment: I don't understand your problem: you write a single `int` (with value 0) into the file, and after that you **are** replacing that value 9 times with the values 1 to 9. In the end your file contains a single `int` value (the value last written, which is 9)

Comment: It is not the `seek(0)` call that deletes the content. It is the `setLength(0)` call that deletes the content. This is currently the first operation after opening the RandomAccessFile. Remove that call and the remainder of the file will be kept.